# Перенос строки в TextArea с помощью shift + enter

Tags: java, javafx, textarea

Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на enter строка не переносилась, а при зажатом shift переносилась.
Сделал `boolean` переменную, отвечающую за зажатый shift, это позволило мне добиться того, чтобы строка не переносилась, пока shift не зажат, но проблема в том, что по умолчанию в `TextArea` строка не переносится при зажатом shift.
При попытке написать `textArea.setText(textArea.getText()+"\n")`, каретка переносится в самое начало, при попытке перенести её в конец, весь текст в `TextArea` выделяется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему таким образом:

```java
boolean shiftPressed = false;
textArea.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, keyEvent -> {
    KeyCode keyCode = keyEvent.getCode();
    if(keyCode.equals(KeyCode.ENTER)) {
        if(!shiftPressed)
            method(); // метод, срабатывающий при нажатии enter без shift
        else
            textArea.insertText(textArea.getCaretPosition(),"\n");
        keyEvent.consume();
    } else if(keyCode.equals(KeyCode.SHIFT))
        shiftPressed = true;
});
textArea.setOnKeyReleased(event -> {
    if(event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.SHIFT))
        shiftPressed = false;
});
```